# Ignoring weekends when using time series operators in Stata

Tags: time-series, stata, missing-data

Is it possible to tell Stata to ignore Saturdays and Sundays when using time series operators such as `L` and `F`?

For example, consider this dataset:

```
date   price    L1.price / L2.price (currently)    L1.price / L2.price (wanted!)
tue    5        . / .                              . / .
wed    .        5 / .                              5 / .
thu    7        . / 5                              . / 5
fri    3        7 / .                              7 / .
sat                        [ignore this row]
sun                        [ignore this row]
mon    1        . / .                              3 / 7
tue    9        1 / .                              1 / 3
```

The third column illustrates Stata's current behavior.

I want it to behave like in the last column.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stata has support for [business calendars](http://www.stata.com/stata12/business-calendars/). Take a look in the manual entry for **[datetime business calendars](http://www.stata.com/bookstore/stata12/pdf/d_datetime_business_calendars.pdf).** They walk you through how you an make one by omitting weekends and holidays.

Comment: On first sight this seems like a perfect solution, I will parse the information and accept your answer when my first thoughts are confirmed =)

Comment: "To make a business calendar, you create a file named calname.stbcal, such as nyse.stbcal." --> but it does not state what the contents of the file are. An empty file results in an error `range undefined`

Comment: That is why I pointed you to the **manual** entry about how to create one. Recent Stata manuals come bundled with Stata as pdf files, so you should have access to this.

Comment: I added a link to the online version of the pdf documentation.